# Migrate intelliJ IDE everything useful from one system to another

Tags: intellij-idea, import, export, intellij-plugin

I have been using the IntelliJ IDE for development on my macbook pro. I am not moving to a new macbook and will be installing the IntelliJ IDE on that system.

How can I migrate everything useful like installed plugins, settings, etc from the older system to the new system.

Answer (score 0):

Use File | Manage IDE Settings... | **Export/Import Settings...** actions.

Note that this action is unavailable if you have a [settings repository](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#settings-repository) configured or if you have enabled [Settings Sync](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html#IDE_settings_sync).

See more in a related [Share IDE settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/sharing-your-ide-settings.html) documentation topic.